# Why is there no pressure in my 06 Chevy Impala...?

Tags: coolant, radiator, overheating, pressure

Boy, what a day I had. Roads were real slippery today in Texas and I skidded and lost control. Next thing you know, I'm in a ditch full of grass, dirt and rocks. I'm still amazed at how little damage the car sustained. Two tires busted and my exhust system was clogged with dirt and grass (cleaned it out) Now I have a problem with my radiator hoses and it's stumped me. No over heating, temp stays in the middle, fans kick on, etc...Only issue is that the hoses are not pressurized.

The upper hose is hot but the lower one is cold. water pump works as I am getting heat, AC compressor works, everything is functioning but I'm just afraid that when I hit the highway it overheats! Are these cars normally like this...?? I have 3.9L IP edition

Comment: When you were testing the hoses, did you let the car get up to operating temperature? If the temps aren't up, the thermostat won't open, and the coolant won't circulate.

Comment: How are you determining pressure?

Comment: Well, the car goes to operating temp and never goes above it.Coolant is flowing. No leaks to be seen at all. I know this car and usually the hoses are very tight once it warms up. I will try getting a new cap and seeing what changes